# List including data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have known that list can include `data.frame`.

This is an example.

```
df<- cbind(column=c(1,2,3), column=c(2,3,4), column=c(3,4,5), column=c(4,5,6))

col<-list()
col[1]<- list(df[,1:2])
col[2]<- list(df[,2:3])
col[3]<- list(df[,3:4])
```

The result of `col` is that

```
col

[[1]]
     column column
[1,]      1      2
[2,]      2      3
[3,]      3      4

[[2]]
     column column
[1,]      2      3
[2,]      3      4
[3,]      4      5

[[3]]
     column column
[1,]      3      4
[2,]      4      5
[3,]      5      6
```

However, when I use `for`.

```
col<-list()

for(i in 1:3){

col[i]<- list(df[,i:i+1])

}
```

The result is that

```
col

[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6
```

What is the different point of these two approaches?
How can I get same result using `for`.?

Comment: By readin [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). Hint: this should be `col[i]<- list(df[,i:(i+1)])`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Arenburg/ Thank you so much! :D. Now, I know what I have mistake in my code. Bracket() is always important thingㅜㅜ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for statement you need to add parenthesis like this:

```
col<-list()

for(i in 1:3){

col[i]<- list(df[,i:(i+1)])

}
```

Basically in your code "i:i+1" is equivalent to "(i:i)+1" since ":" has priority over "+" on this operation... or in other words you are doing (i+1):(i+1)